# Phonegap app - json + php - crossdomain not working

Tags: json, cordova, cross-domain

i have a problem with the phonegap app.

I try to connect with ajax post with simple php file which return my an array in my app.
This is simple example/tutorial from net. I try everything i read a tousends of topics, but i don't know where is problem.

My index of the phonegap app

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Minimal AppLaud App</title>

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function connect(e)
{
var term= {button:e};
$.ajax({
url:'http://domain.pl/replay.php',
type:'POST',
data:term,
dataType:'json',
error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
alert('no connection');},
timeout:6000,
success:function(data){
$("#result").html("");
for(var i in data){
$("#result").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
}
}
});}
</script>

  </head>
  <body id="stage" class="theme">


<center><b>Bikes or Cars</b></center>
<center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="cars" /></center>
<center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="bikes" /></center>

<center><b>Results</b></center>
<ul id="result"></ul>


  </body>
</html>
```

And my replay.php file

```
<?php
$choice =$_POST["button"];
$cars = array("Honde", "BMW" , "Ferrari");
$bikes = array("Ducaite", "Royal Enfield" , "Harley Davidson");
if($choice == "cars") print json_encode($cars);
else print json_encode($bikes);
?>
```

I add domain whitelist to cordova and config xml files

```
<access origin=".*"/>
```

And i don't have any ideas what is wrong.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 <access origin=".*"/>
```

with

```
 <access origin="*"/>
```

Maybe it will solve a problem.

Comment: @lzymla Well, if you have already set access origin to *, and it didn't help, than it will be good to see your error info from post request error:function, because i don't see any problems in your JS-code (can't say anything surely about PHP-code) and there are no other answers/suggestions yet.

Comment: in chrome.console i have error the connect function is not defined, when i click button: "Uncaught ReferenceError: connect is not defined"

Comment: @lzymla I looked once again at your code and actually didn't see including of JQuery... After i include it - it works for me, even though i use cordova 2.9.0

Comment: many thanks for Yours replay, yes I have problem within iclude jQuery, but now i have a XMLHttpRequest error - "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://autotracker.pl/replay.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: I just try to create new project, with set orign=".*" and without dot, try also set to my domain, but still this not working and i don't many ideas what is wrong :((

Comment: @lzymla two more questions: do you run your app on iOS? And did you try to make request to google.com?

Comment: i try this on android 4.1.2 on phone (and on website), i didn't try request to google, how?

Comment: i make new app and i don't have problem with send data by json from phonegap storage to server php script, but i still have problem with the answer from server to phonegap ;/

Comment: @lzymla it looks strange, maybe you have problems in server config. But you can try some non-standard ideas: 1). Manually set $.support.cors and $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages to true before request. 2). Add to $.ajax xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}. 3). Change dataType from 'json' to 'jsonp' (in such case, you should modify server answer to jsonp-format).